# How i generate X random number and store them into data base against one ID

Tags: php, random

Generate random numbers entered in text field and want to store them in database against one ID number.

```
<html>
        <form action="loops.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="emp"  value="<?php $abd ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
        </form>  
    <?php 
    $var_value = $_POST['emp'];

        function gen_random_string($length=6)
        {
            $chars ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
            $final_rand ='';
            for($i=0;$i<$length; $i++)
            {
                $final_rand .= $chars[ rand(0,strlen($chars)-1)];
            }
            return $final_rand;
        }
        for($i=1; $i<=$var_value; $i++){
            $abc = gen_randomenter code here_string($length=6);
             echo $abc."<br>"; //generates a string
        }
        ?>
    </html>
```

Comment: It is not enough to just tell us what you want or need - you need to describe to us what your _specific_ problem is. Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3qn2qtbk/7/) should work for you:

I changed the PHP to javascript. You can now write something in the text input and it'll generate a random string, based on the length. It'll store the generated string as a value for the hidden field. You can then send the form data to a PHP script which can handle the DB actions. The random ID will be set in `$_POST['id']`

Comment: i want to generate more then 100 random numbers on submit button and store that generated numbers in database in one ID

Comment: @AsifAhmad I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but i've updated the JSFiddle. Take another look